# 19.04 Bluetooth Audio (LDAC, aptxhd) - Choppy, Stutter

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 19.04, headphones

I have a pair of Sony [WH-H900N](https://www.sony.com/electronics/headband-headphones/wh-h900n) headphones. They work perfectly on android (LDAC), Mac (aptx-hd (no LDAC available)), and Windows (Aptx-hd). LDAC is astounding quality for wireless, which is why I'm pursuing it on Linux.

On Ubuntu, they were working only on some kind of "headset" codec that sounded terrible (scratchy, telephone quality). I followed the instructions here: https://github.com/EHfive/pulseaudio-modules-bt. This enabled LDAC and similar:

[LDAC enabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDlUs.png)

The sound is much improved. However, the sound is choppy to the point of uselessness. Distance is not an issue (I'm right at the source).

My motherboard is [a MSI Gaming Pro Carbon AC](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B450-GAMING-PRO-CARBON-AC/Specification), which shows an Intel chip (Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 9260).

Adjusting the selection in the menu as shown doesn't actually change it, when I click back, it goes back to LDAC.

I would have thought if the board was not compatible with LDAC, it simply would not have worked. Is that incorrect?

Is there anything I can do to get BT audio to work on Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you forced LDAC quality to 990kbps or used variable bitrate? `EHfive/pulseaudio-modules-bt` fork also enables other codecs. Have you tried them? Is sound still choppy?

Comment: I had the same issue with an inferior network card in a laptop with a 4th generation processor, it worked certainly well when I turned off the wifi and started listening to music without having many applications open, now with an Intel Wireless AC 9560 and a 10th processor generation I do not present that problem even with the wifi on and with several applications open at the same time

Comment: Same issue with Sennheiser headphones. It does feel performance related because it stutters the most when a lot of noise is happening (i.e. intense gaming).